# (Spring) When using PUT method, @CreationTimestamp fails

Tags: spring, put

I have this API that uses @CreationTimestamp to auto-generate the date when any information is added to the database, and it works. The problem is, when i use the PUT method in a specific information of the database, the generated Date disappears.
This is how things are structured:

```
...
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "CreationDate", length = 29)
@CreationTimestamp
private Date CreationDate;
...
```

This is how my PUT method is:

```
@PutMapping("/SomeURL/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public User editUser(@RequestBody @Valid User T, @PathVariable Integer id) {
return userRepository.save(T);
}
```

When I use this,  the generated Date from the @CreationTimestamp disappears, and that field becomes blank (null).

Why is this happening?

OBS: I dont think is necessary, but this is my POST method:

```
@PostMapping("/someURL")
public User addUser(@RequestBody @Valid User T) {
return userRepository.save(T);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation date will be updated when calling `save` method within your `editUser` method. The entity possibly does not contain this value, therefore null will be set as updated value. (you can try to debug this to check)

Change the column annotation as followed:

```
@Column(name = "CreationDate", length = 29, nullable = false, updatable = false)
```

This should prevent the once created date to be updated.

HTH